# After last iteration setInterval returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I'm trying to make `background-color` to swap after X time, and its working BUT after last iteration where step is set to 0, what I'm getting is `undefined` and I can't figure it out why : /

```js
const foo = () => {
  const colors = [{
      primary: 'LightGreen',
      secondary: '#7fe27f'
    },
    {
      primary: "Gold",
      secondary: '#efc900'
    },
    {
      primary: "#1590FF",
      secondary: '#0479FF'
    },
    {
      primary: "#00BFFF",
      secondary: '#06ace3'
    }
  ]
  let step = -1
  return setInterval(() => {
    step === colors.length ? step = 0 : step++
      return console.log(colors[step]);
  }, 2000)
}
```

Any ideas why is that happening? And how I could fix it?

Comment: _"and its working"_ - Really? `foo` will always [return the id of the created timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). The "inner" `return` would return `undefined` because `console.log()` doesn't return anything. But -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call); And that's not the way how the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) should be used.

Comment: It's just quick drawing from my react code, I wanted to omit all useEffect, useState and unnecessary code for simplicity ;) But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `step` is equal to `colors.length - 1`, you will perform `step++`, which will make `step === colors.length`. Then you will access `colors[colors.length]` which is `undefined`.

You have to check whether `step === colors.length - 1` in your condition.

But a better solution would be to use the remainder operator. You can just do:

```
console.log(colors[step++ % colors.length]);
```